# Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in laravel database Connection

Tags: php, laravel

I try to write my command in larqavel and there is a problem with my database connection I have a query to get my tables records and after that, I write a foreach to process records one by one, everything was ok but in recent days I got an error

also, I try to get my record with different methods

```
$this->result = results::where('checked',false)->get();

// and this one

$this->result = \DB::select('select * from results where checked = ?', array(0));
```

and I got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /etc/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 336

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:336
    332|             );
    333| 
    334|             $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
    335| 
  > 336|             $statement->execute();
    337| 
    338|             return $statement->fetchAll();
    339|         });
    340|     }
```

I change in the file and set 0 for maximum execution time, even I try to set it on the first line of my command by I still get error

**update**

also I try `set_time_limit(-1);` its still didn't work

I use PHP 7.4.5 in ParrotOS

```
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Jun  3 2020 20:55:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Is your "foreach" performing the query or is the query already finished and the foreach is over the fetched data? Either there's something terribly wrong with your database (eg no indexes) or you're doing too many SQL requests.

Comment: @Scuzzy its just fetch data and at the end of each record set checked = 1 and update

Comment: Perhaps you need to process fewer records at a time or change your update statement to bulk update records.